# Controller methods not are called on subsequent loads

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have 2 pages defined in my route -

```
/** router.js **/
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('index', {path: ''});
    this.route('item', {path: 'item/:item_id'});
});
```

Each page has a method called "itemlist"

```
/** controllers/index.js **/

var IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({

   itemlist: function () {

     console.log('indexcontroller - itemlist'); 
     var ref = this;
     $.getJSON('/api', function (data) {
         ref.set('items', data);
     });
     return [];

   }.property('items')

});

/** controllers/item.js **/

var ItemController = Ember.Controller.extend({

   itemlist: function () {

     console.log('itemcontroller - itemlist');
     var ref = this;
     $.getJSON('/api', function (data) {
         ref.set('items', data);
     });
     return [];

   }.property('items')

});
```

My templates index.hbs and item.hbs both call the methods as follows :

```
{{#each item in itemlist}}
...
{{/each}}
```

I can see that the log messages are printed on my console on first load - when I first navigate to '/' and when I first navigate to '/event/xxxx'. When I repeat the actions, the methods are not called again. Could this be a cache issue with my browser or is there a way to flush my properties before a route change?

EDIT --

I've managed to repeat it with this jsbin - 
**http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kigumezo/1/edit (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kigumezo/1)**

The 'called' message only comes the first time /test/:test_name is visited. I realize I'm missing some fundamental knowledge about this but I can't seem to find what the problem is. I want that property to be refreshed every time I visit a different url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue in my case by just looking at the type of the model passed to setupController. On the second instance of the call, I was getting an item object and not a string which referred to my item_id. I'll look into the matter but for now, its closed.

If someone can please post an explanation for this, that would be great.

Thanks to everyone to tried to help out!

Answer (score 4):

The `{{each}}` helper needs to be passed an enumerable object (i.e. a list of objects), you can't just call it on a method. This is definitely the wrong way of calling a controller action.

Also the closing tag for the `{{#each}}` should be `{{/each}}`, not `{{/itemlist}}`

Comment: What you have looks good - could you provide more code (e.g. where do you get `objs` from and what is `eventlist`) and maybe put together a jsBin?

Comment: Please see updated coded. I get the data from a JSON API and temporarily fill it with an empty array before the data is retrieved from the API. Is that a good way to do it? I would do a jsBin entry but the API is not public at the moment.